# Service not getting started when running app - How to explicitly start a Service?

Tags: android, android-service

I have declared two services in my Android app, but neither of them is getting started when running my application. It doesn't show any type of error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="net.simplifiedcoding.firebasecloudmessaging">

    <!-- Adding Internet Permission -->

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- 
            Defining Services
        -->
        <service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried these:

1) Include `android:enabled="true"` in your services tag as:

```
  <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService" />
```

2) Start a [Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) with [`startService()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand(android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int)) method using `onStartCommand()` method.Click the hyperlinks for relevant information.

PS: Seems you've many Activities in your App and wants to start the Service in the `MainActivity` itself. Include your Java Classes code for those Services too. It will help users to help you better.